Upgrade to 24.04 fails with nondescript error
The system updater keeps telling me I should upgrade to 24.04, however every time I try to do so, it fails with this nothing of an error message:
"Error during update. A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry."
The output window is completely empty. Yes, my network connection is working. Yes, I have restarted the PC multiple times.

I do not think it is telling you you should update it is simply offering you the option.
